# How to generate source code using external tool from configure itself?

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I need to generate a `.c` and `.h` from a Google Protocol Buffer spec `.proto` in my build.

Currently I followed the approach of manually recording the dependencies to my generated `.h` file. That is, I added several:

```
somefilethatincludesthegenerated.$(OBJEXT): mygenerated.h
```

and that together with my rules to build `mygenerated.h` and `mygenerated.c` works. I know about `BUILT_SOURCES` but that only works for `make all` not for `make mytarget`.

So I wanted to explore the possibility of generating the sources from `configure` instead, as described in the [Automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Built-Sources-Example-1).

The `AC_CONFIG_FILES` would allow me to generate `mygenerated.h` from a `mygenerated.h.in` but really this file is not meant to be generated from a template. The files are to be generated by using an external tool called `protoc`. In my  `Makefile.am` file the rule to build the generated sources is:

```
mygenerated.c mygenerated.c: myprotofile.proto
  $(PROTOC) --proto_path=$(srcdir) --c_out=$(builddir) $^
```

How can achieve something similar from within `configure` itself?. What I'm after is to build the generated sources always, and before any other target (`BUILT_SOURCES` will not work for targets other than `all`, `check`, and some others)

Comment: You will have to compile the proto file to generate the sources. Take a look at the [protobuf manual](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview).

Comment: I already know that, as it's described in the the question itself. Now I want to compile the proto file from the `configure` script itself instead of compile it in the `Makefile`

Comment: why do you want to compile code in the `configure` step? `configure` really tries to separate the steps of *configuring*  and *building*; you should not try to mingle them.

Comment: Well, generating sources in `configure` is one of the options described in the [GNU Automake manual 9.4.1][http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Built-Sources-Example.html] so I wanted to try it. The main advantage it's to be sure that the generated sources are already there when you `make <target>`. `BUILT_SOURCES` and `Record dependencies manually` have their drawbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suceeded using [`AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.60/html_node/Configuration-Commands.html) instead of `AC_CONFIG_FILES`.

So to run `protoc` (or `protoc-c` like in this case)  from `configure` add the following to `configure.ac`:

```
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([src/mygenerated.h],
                   [protoc-c --proto_path=src --c_out=src src/myprotofile.proto])
```

Then when you run `./configure` you will see a

```
config.status: executing src/mygenerated.h commands
```

**Note that if you modify the `.proto` file you need to rerun `./configure`**. This is a drawback of the "generate sources from configure" approach.